# Merge data based on three rules

Tags: r, dataframe

Using a dframe such as:

```
dframe <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = c("2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03", 
"2008-11-05"), text_sth = c("another text", "other", "another one", 
"test", "text_sth", "another text", "another text", "other", 
"another one", "test", "text_sth", "another text", "other", "text here"
), name = c("Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", 
"Google", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", "Yahoo", 
"Amazon", "Amazon"), label = c("pre", "pre", "after", "after", 
"after", "after", "pre", "pre", "after", "after", "after", "after", 
"pre", "after")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
))
```

How is it possible to make a double merge which first check if column "label" is pre or after, after check if the column "name" and merge all by id. Example expected output:

```
  id                               text_sth   name label
1                     another text other Google   pre
1 another one test text_sth another text Google after
1                     another text other  Yahoo   pre
1 another one test text_sth another text  Yahoo after
1                                  other Amazon   pre
1                              text here Amazon after
```

Comment: Can you explain how these rows are selected ?

Comment: You’re trying to merge the object with itself?

Comment: @42- From one point of view yes

Comment: @RonakShah they selected based on name column and merge it into two case, based on pre or after. Based on this the text_sth column merge all rows into one separated by space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dframe2 <- dframe %>%
  group_by(id, name, label) %>%
  summarize(text_sth = paste(text_sth, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup() 

dframe2
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      id name   label text_sth                              
#   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                 
# 1     1 Amazon after text here                             
# 2     1 Amazon pre   other                                 
# 3     1 Google after another one test text_sth another text
# 4     1 Google pre   another text other                    
# 5     1 Yahoo  after another one test text_sth another text
# 6     1 Yahoo  pre   another text other
```

Additional steps to order and sort the data frame to be as the same as your example output.

```
dframe3 <- dframe2 %>%
  select(id, text_sth, name, label) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = unique(dframe$name)),
         label = factor(label, levels = unique(dframe$label))) %>%
  arrange(id, name, label) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
dframe3
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      id text_sth                               name   label
#   <int> <chr>                                  <chr>  <chr>
# 1     1 another text other                     Google pre  
# 2     1 another one test text_sth another text Google after
# 3     1 another text other                     Yahoo  pre  
# 4     1 another one test text_sth another text Yahoo  after
# 5     1 other                                  Amazon pre  
# 6     1 text here                              Amazon after
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use `aggregate()`.

```
res <- aggregate(. ~ id + name + label, dframe, paste, collapse = " ")[, -4]
res
#   id   name label                               text_sth
# 1  1 Amazon after                              text here
# 2  1 Google after another one test text_sth another text
# 3  1  Yahoo after another one test text_sth another text
# 4  1 Amazon   pre                                  other
# 5  1 Google   pre                     another text other
# 6  1  Yahoo   pre                     another text other
```

If you absolutely need the specified order in your example output, you may use this additional code after:

```
res[order(as.character(factor(res$name, labels=c(3, 1, 2))), rev(res$label)), c(1, 4, 2:3)]
#   id                               text_sth   name label
# 5  1                     another text other Google   pre
# 2  1 another one test text_sth another text Google after
# 6  1                     another text other  Yahoo   pre
# 3  1 another one test text_sth another text  Yahoo after
# 4  1                                  other Amazon   pre
# 1  1                              text here Amazon after
```